# Automating of vue.js app with Gitlab deployment to Firebase

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Am facing an issue with the pipelines, I have included some scripts in my `YAML` file to automate the deployment of a **Vue** app to Firebase. But when I push the code to a GitLab **Merge/Pull Request (PR/MR)**, there's no pipeline running. I also included the Environment variable of `FIREBASE_TOKEN` on Gitlab.

Below is my `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file :

```
image: rambabusaravanan/firebase

stages:
  - deploy

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REPO"

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - yarn
    - yarn run build
    - firebase use HFB-Frontend-mock --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
    - firebase deploy --only hosting -m "Pipe $CI_PIPELINE_ID Build $CI_BUILD_ID" --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

This is the tutorial I was following [tutorial for CI/CD Gitlab](https://medium.com/@rambabusaravanan/firebase-hosting-deployment-automation-with-gitlab-ci-f3fad9130d62)

Then, this is how the PR/MR displays without the pipeline running :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CI config [file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/#creating-a-gitlab-ciyml-file) doesn't have the correct extension.

This not `.gitlab-ci.yaml` but `.gitlab-ci.yml`  (`.yml` instead of `.yaml`)

Also, the pipeline will be triggered after the merge on `master`. If you want the [pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/merge_request_pipelines/) running when a MR is submited, you need to add :

```
  only:
  - merge_requests
```

Comment: Hey Nicholas , thanks for the reply actual the `yaml` part was a typo, I have `yml`.  Maybe let me try your other solution for `merge_requests`.

Comment: Maybe another question would be, should I remove `master` and I replace with `merge_requests` or I shouldn't do that ?

Comment: Actually your solution has worked after removing `master` and I replaced `merge_request`, but my concern is, will it run on master after the merge request ?

Comment: Yes, if you let both, it will run on both.